# I am using elasticserach-1.4.1 and when I'm trying to create an index, I am getting the following error

Tags: elasticsearch

## My Query

```
curl -XPOST 10.1.1.108:9200/fw -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 0,
        "index.store.compress.stored":"true",
        "index.store.compress.tv":"true",
    "index.query.default_field":"rawlog",
        "compress.default.type":"snappy",
    "index.merge.policy.floor_segment":100,
        "index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once":100,
        "es.batch.size.bytes" : "134217728",
        "index.translog.flush_threshold_size": "536870912",
        "network.tcp.keep_alive": "true",
        "index.store.type":"mmapfs",
    "client.transport.ping_timeout":"180s"

    },
    "mappings" : {
        "logs" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : true,"compress":true,"compress_threshold":"100b","compress.default.type":"snappy"},      
            "_all":{"enabled" : false},  
            "properties" : {                
        "cust_id": {"type" : "long","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "devi_id": {"type" : "long","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "evt_date": {"type" : "date","index" : "not_analyzed","format" : "yyyy-MM-dd" ,"fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "first_occurance": {"type" : "date","format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
                "hr":{ "type" : "string","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "type": {"type" : "string","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "action": {"type" : "string","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "status" : { "type" : "string","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
                "src" : { "type" : "long","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"},"doc_values_format" : "disk"},     
        "dst" : { "type" : "long","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "dst_port" : { "type" : "integer","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "rowid": {"type" : "long","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "url": {"type" : "string","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "sentinel_id": {"type" : "long","index" : "not_analyzed","fielddata": {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"},
        "src_name": {"type" : "string"},
        "dst_name": {"type" : "string"},
        "rawlog" : { "type" : "string"}
      }
        }
    }
}'
```

## Error

> {"error":"MapperParsingException[mapping [logs]]; nested:
>   ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find doc_values_format
>   [disk]]; ","status":400}

Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"} ,is there any other option available for using "doc" format in elasticserach-1.4.1.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `doc_values_format` was [removed](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/7604) in elasticsearch 1.4 - try removing that from your mapping

Comment: But we are using doc format only.Is there any alternative way available.Please suggest.

Comment: @Ananta You don't need to set doc_values_format to use doc_values - setting the field data format as you already are should be enough

Comment: Will it support "doc_values_format" : "disk" by default.

Comment: I don't know - the github issue I linked to has more details including migration path if you were using this

Comment: Instead of using {"format": "doc_values"}, "doc_values_format" : "disk"} ,is there any other option available for using "doc" format in elasticserach-1.4.1.Please suggest me.